# How to apply Metadata from a ViewModel to the View in WPF with MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have a viewModel with properties like the following and a set of specific attributes used throughout the viewmodels.

```
public class MyViewModel : BaseModel
{
    [StringLength(50), Required]
    [SetLockedForExistingEntities]
    public string FirstName { get ...  set ... }

    public bool IsInNewMode { get; }
}
```

Now I want to apply such metaData in a view in a consistent way. Like... If bound, set TextBox maxlength from the MaxLengthAttribute. If SetLockedForExistingEntitiesAttribute is set, disable the control in case viewModel is not in some 'New' Mode etc..

Is that doable/a good idea to do with a custom MarkupExtension that replaces "Binding" for VM Bindings? Or would it be better to use a Behavior (applied via attached property) which tries to apply anything it can from the bound ViewModel property to the control it is attached to?

Usage would be like

(A) Attached dependencyproperty that reads the binding from TextBox.Text and applies behaviors
    
    `<TextBox Text="{Binding Model.FirstName, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" "bb:MyBindingHelper.ApplyViewModelBehaviors="True" />`

(B) Custom MarkupExtension that does all in one

    `<TextBox Text="{BindingWithModelBasedBehaviors Model.FirstName}" />`

Answer (score 2):

You could write a markup extension that gets the property from the datacontext and reads attributes.
That would be kind of complicated but you can get the property name of properties where the source changed event was raised.

That looks rather like validation to me.
You could implement inotifydataerrorinfo in a base viewmodel and write code there that validates properties using attributes.
That's how the code in this works:
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/WPF-Entity-Framework-MVVM-78cdc204

That works by the view telling the viewmodel which property's value just passed to the viewmodel.
You can extend the method you use for raising property changed to pass the property name to the validation.
Or you could even do the check from a method called in the property setter before you set the value on a property and not set the value if the new one  fails validation.

As a specific property fails validation in a particular way you could run an action.
The production code version of that app I linked also has a dictionary of predicates used as well as attributes. They could have code in them references and sets other viewmodel properties.

Comment: Validation is already handled using IDataErrorInfo. Currently i have e.G. in xaml:
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Model.FirstName, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"      bb:MyBindingHelper.ApplyMaxLength="True" bb:MyBindingHelper.ApplyLockableField="True" />

Now i consider to 

(a)merge that helper properties into a MyBindingHelper.ApplyViewModelBehaviors="True" or

(b)merge it with the binding in some kind of
  <TextBox Text="{BindingWithModelBasedBehaviors PersonModel.Vorname}" />

And let that markupextension do all the things consistently